# Kendo UI Chart DataBinding not firing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm looking into checking the data source after it is bound to see how many items there are.  For some reason I can't get the dataBound or dataBinding events to even fire.

The data is actually being passed into a function so when the grid is created it has the data locally.

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/IjAKo/2

Source Code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
  function onDataBinding(e) {
    console.log('here');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = $("#grid").kendoChart({
      chartArea: {
        height: 250,
      },
      legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
          font: "bold 10px Arial",
        }
      },
      seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        spacing: 0,
        overlay: {
          gradient: "none"
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: "ESCROW",
        color: "#cccbcb",
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
      }, {
        name: "NON-ESCROW",
        color: "#406f8c",
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
      }],
      categoryAxis: {
        line: {
          visible: false
        },
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        majorGridLines: {
          visible: false
        }
      },
      valueAxis: {
        labels: {
          format: "{0:N0}"
        },
        line: {
          visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
          visible: false
        },
        max: 20
      },
      tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0:N0}"
      },
      dataBinding: onDataBinding  // tried to do it here.

    });
    // tried to bind after initialization
    chart.bind("dataBound", function(e) {
      alert('here')
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not `dataBinding` event in chart, there is only `dataBound`. This event fires only when the chart has specified `dataSource`, even empty, so you have to add line like so to your chart:

```
dataSource: {},
```

And one more thing: in your example you use local data, so if you first create your chart and then bind function to `dataBound`, the event will not fire cuz data is already bound. Define dataBound event in chart constructor:

```
dataBound: function(e) { console.log('data bound') },
```

Fixed example: http://dojo.telerik.com/IjAKo/4

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of obscure but it does work.  Didn't realize I had to have an empty dataSource.

Comment: If you leave it like it is your `dataSource` property will have 0 dataItems, because you specified your data explicitly in chart series. You can find amount of data series directly in chart options. To have data in your chart `dataSource`, you have to rearange the chart costructor. See this example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/local-data-binding